# Twilio and OpenAI integration for AI voice communication to the user

Tags: node.js, twilio, artificial-intelligence, twilio-api, openai-api

I am trying to have a voice communication between user and AI assistant using twilio and OpenAI using nodejs code. I have created the urls and need real time communication like if openAI is responding it will be said by the twilio method as well so that we do not have to wait for reponse from openAI and tranfer voice to the user. I have tried and it working fine without stream but I need to run it at real time just like we talk each other over phone call.

```
Here what I tried ---

const apiResponse = require("../helpers/apiResponse");
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const twilio = require("twilio");
const http = require("http");

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const { parse } = require("path");
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);


exports.outgoingCall = async (req, res) => {
  client.calls
    .create({
      url: "http://192.241.128.213/voice.xml",
      //   twiml: '<Response><Say voice="woman">Hi, Thanks for calling. Please let me know how can I help you?</Say><Redirect method="POST">https://de13-223-178-212-10.ngrok-free.app/api/v1/voip/gather-info</Redirect></Response>',
      to: "+17653990096",
      from: "+14708024685",
    })
    .then((call) => {
      console.log(call.sid);
      return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, "Sucessful", {});
    });
};

/**
 * gather information about the voice call
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
exports.gatherInfo = async function (req, res) {
  console.log("gather-info");
  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  console.log("req.body", req.body);
  console.log("SpeechResult", req.body.SpeechResult);
  //   if (req.body.SpeechResult) {
  //     console.log("in req.body.SpeechResult");

  //     // ai stream
  //     twiml.say("Thank you for your feedback");
  //     client.calls(req.body.CallSid).update({ status: "completed" });
  //     twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
  //   } else {
  const gather = twiml.gather({
    action: "/api/v1/voip/gather-info",
    method: "POST",
    partialResultCallback: "/api/v1/voip/gather-info-partial",
    input: "speech",
  });
  if (
    req.body.SpeechResult &&
    req.body.SpeechResult != undefined &&
    req.body.SpeechResult != ""
  ) {
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion(
      {
        model: "gpt-4",
        messages: [
          {
            role: "system",
            content:
              "You are a helpful interior designer assistant. Please reply in maximum 1 line.",
          },
          { role: "user", content: req.body.SpeechResult },
        ],
        stream: true,
      },
      { responseType: "stream" }
    );
    response.data
      .on("data", (data) => {
        const lines = data
          .toString()
          .split("\n")
          .filter((line) => line.trim() !== "");
        console.log(lines);
        for (const line of lines) {
          const message = line.replace(/^data: /, "");
          if (message === "[DONE]") {
            break; // Stream finished
          }
          try {
            // console.log('message---',message)
            const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
            if (parsed.choices[0].delta.content != undefined) {
              console.log(parsed.choices[0].delta.content);
              twiml.say(parsed.choices[0].delta.content);
            } else {
              continue;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(
              "Could not JSON parse stream message",
              message,
              error
            );
            continue;
          }
        }
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        twiml.say("Anything else you are looking for?");
        twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
        console.log("stream ended");
      });
      console.log('before promise..');
      await new Promise( r=> setTimeout(r,3000));
    // setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("ddddddddd");
    //   twiml.say("Anything else you are looking for?");
    //   twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
    // }, 1000);
    // console.log("openn ai response---", response.data);
    // twiml.say(response?.data?.choices[0]?.message?.content);
    // twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
  }
  //   }

  res.type("text/xml");
  res.send(twiml.toString());
};


/**
 * gather information partial
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
exports.gatherInfoPartial = async function (req, res) {
  console.log("gather-info-partial");
  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  // console.log("req.body",req.body)
  console.log("SpeechResult", req.body.StableSpeechResult);
  twiml.say("can plesae let me know what the service you are looking for?");
  res.type("text/xml");
  res.send(twiml.toString());
};
```

route file --

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const CallController = require("../controller/CallController");

router.post("/gather-info", CallController.gatherInfo);
router.post("/gather-info-partial", CallController.gatherInfoPartial);

router.get("/outgoing-call", CallController.outgoingCall);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am searching on this project from 2 months and i have collect a lot of data and i can give you a better answer first of all Enhanced `gatherInfo` Function.

```
exports.gatherInfo = async function (req, res) {
  const twiml = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  if (req.body.SpeechResult) {
    try {
      const response = await openai.createChatCompletion(
        {
          model: "gpt-4",
          messages: [
            {
              role: "system",
              content:
                "You are a helpful assistant. Please reply concisely.",
            },
            { role: "user", content: req.body.SpeechResult },
          ],
          stream: true,
        }
      );

      response.data
        .on('data', (data) => {
          const message = data.toString();
          if (message.includes('[DONE]')) {
            return; // End the stream
          }
          try {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
            if (parsed.choices && parsed.choices[0].message && parsed.choices[0].message.content) {
              twiml.say(parsed.choices[0].message.content);
            }
          } catch (parseError) {
            console.error("Error parsing OpenAI response:", parseError);
          }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          twiml.say("Is there anything else I can help with?");
          twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
          console.log("OpenAI stream ended.");
        })
        .on('error', (streamError) => {
          console.error("Stream encountered an error:", streamError);
          twiml.say("I'm sorry, I encountered an error.");
          twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
        });

    } catch (openAIError) {
      console.error("OpenAI API error:", openAIError);
      twiml.say("I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding right now.");
      twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No speech result received.");
    twiml.say("I didn't catch that. Could you please repeat?");
    twiml.redirect("/api/v1/voip/gather-info");
  }

  res.type("text/xml");
  res.send(twiml.toString());
};
```

**key improvements include:**

**Try-Catch Blocks:** Added for robust error handling, with an outer block for OpenAI API errors and an inner block within the data event listener for parsing errors.

**Improved Logging:** Detailed logging is implemented for each error, aiding in quick identification and resolution of issues.

**User Feedback:** In case of errors, users are informed via Twilio's say method, maintaining engagement and clarity.

**Handling No Input:** The system now gracefully handles situations where no speech result is received, prompting the user again for input.

what is your guidance to me on a advanced setup using VoIP services like Twilio for call handling, allowing more online processing and avoiding direct Android interfacing?

**VoIP Costs:** Worried about the per-minute charges and potential call quality issues, especially with long-distance connections that might introduce latency.

**TTS and STT Services:** Impressed by the quality of modern text-to-speech and speech-to-text services, but the cost per word and potential data transmission delays are concerns.

**Bandwidth:** I have a 5G internet setup with speeds between 270 and 650 Mbps, which seems cost-effective and potentially more reliable than fiber internet for this use case.

**I'm seeking insights on:**

1. **Estimated Costs:** For VoIP, TTS, and STT services.
2. **Managing Delays and Voice Quality:** Recommendations or personal experiences, especially regarding using OpenAI in such projects.

**What I'm Expecting:**

1. Seamless integration for the chatbot to receive and answer calls.
2. Minimal latency in voice transmission. Cost-effective solutions for VoIP, TTS, and STT services.